# Woocommerce Subscription - add coupon to existing subscription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, subscription

I am looking to add the function, where I can offer a user a discount code that affects their next subscription amount.

For example:

- I give customer code 1234 to give them 10% off their next months renewal
- They enter the code in their My Account area and then Stripe knows that next month to charge them 10% less then the usual amount.

I have seen a few questions on here asking something similar but no answers so thought I would ask myself and see if anyone can offer their assistance.

Comment: Have you read the guide on subscription coupons with Woocommerce? It looks to be exactly what you're after: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/store-manager-guide/?_ga=2.196148652.1013478205.1604587664-2071328294.1603126887#section-9

Comment: Hi, yes I have been through that. By default you are only allowed to add a coupon from the start of a subscription. Ie a reoccurring one or an initial discount. I am talking about adding one when someone already has a subscription so it acts as a discount on their next months renewal

Comment: @JamesDeadman have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. The coupon has a discount type of Recurring Product % Discount and it applies on the next renewal(s) . You can set for how many renewals it is applied to. The code to apply it is:

```
$subscription->apply_coupon('your-coupon-code');
```

And I use it like this on the form handler:

```
if(isset($_POST['sid']) && $_POST['sid'] != ""){
            $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $_POST['sid'] );
            if($subscription->get_status()=="active"){
                $subscription->apply_coupon($_POST['coupon']); // returns true on success
            }
        }
```